# how to define the flow model and volume model in Modelica components?

Tags: modelica, fluid-dynamics

I am learning how to build a thermo-fluid model with Modelica, I notice that in order to reduce the nonlinearity, it is recommended to use two different models: flow model and volume model, here is the explanation I found in a commercial library, but I am not sure how to arrange the equation in the components to realize this idea.
So I am looking for some papers and examples about how to use this idea in Modelica coding.

> The flow port which indicates that a flow model is directly coupled to
>   it on the inside of the component, i.e. pressure from this port is
>   further processed to compute e.g. mass flow rate. It is recommended to
>   connect this port with a corresponding VolumePort in order to obtain
>   an alternating flow model-volume system model structure. If two models
>   are connected with their ports being both of this class, non-linear
>   equation systems for the algebraic pressure in the ports may be
>   created and require an initial guess value.

[image: el]

[image]
[image]